# No packet crossing default gateway

Tags: routing, tcpdump

I have two Ubuntu 17.04 nodes, A (10.0.9.2) and B (10.0.9.1).

I have set B as default gateway of A, using the command:

`route add default gw 10.0.9.1 interface vi4`.

Yet, when I traceroute 8.8.8.8 from A, I cannot capture any packet crossing B using tcpdump.

Note that no shorter prefix rule exists for 8.8.8.8 in A.

Comment: Can you please add the traceroute output and the output of `ip route show` and `ip rule`?